# How to rotate words by their index positions?

Tags: java

I am trying to read an input file containing two sentences on new line. I have to write a code to rotate every word in a sentence to the right side and write to output.txt file. For example, input.txt file contains following:

```
Hello World.
Welcome to java programming.
```

Let's say "Hello" has index 1. It should rotate to the right by 1 position i.e. **oHell**. "World." has index 2, it should rotate to the right by 2 positions i.e. **ldWor.**, maintaining the position of period(.)

And on the next line index again begins with 1. i.e. "Welcome" with index 1 should rotate to the right by 1 position, "to" with index 2 should rotate to the right by 2 positions, "java" with index 3 should rotate to the right by 3 positions, "programming" with index 4 should rotate to the right by 4 positions.

So, the output should be:

```
oHell ldWor.
eWelcom to avaj mingprogram.
```

**Below is my code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    rotate();
}

    private static void rotate() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
        FileWriter outputFile = new FileWriter("output.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String last = "";
            if(line.charAt(line.length()-1) == '.'){
                last = ".";
                line = line.substring(0,line.length()-1);
            }
            String str[] = line.split(" ");
            outputFile.write(IntStream.range(0, str.length-1).mapToObj(i -> rotate(str[i], i)).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")) +last+ "\n");
        }
        inputFile.close();
        outputFile.close();
        scanner.close();
    }

    private static String rotate(String str, int position) {
        return str.substring(str.length()-position)+str.substring(0,str.length()-position);
    }
```

**Output getting:**

```
Hello.
Welcome ot vaja.
```

**Output expected:**

```
oHell ldWor.
eWelcom to avaj mingprogram.
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: You've considered only `.` as the punctuation mark in your code. However, a punctuation mark can be one of `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~`. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotate the words of the string in the following way:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "Hello World.", "Welcome to java programming OP." };

        // Test
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(rotate(s));
        }
    }

    static String rotate(String str) {
        // Split the string on space(s)
        String[] words = str.split("\\s+");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            // If `words[i]` contains a punctuation mark at the end, drop it.
            char lastChar = words[i].charAt(words[i].length() - 1);
            boolean noPunct = false;
            if (Character.isDigit(lastChar) || Character.isLetter(lastChar)) {
                noPunct = true;
            }
            String word = !noPunct ? words[i].substring(0, words[i].length() - 1) : words[i];

            // Rotate the word
            String rotatedWord = "";
            if (i > word.length()) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                    rotatedWord = word.substring(word.length() - j % word.length() - 1)
                            + word.substring(0, word.length() - j % word.length() - 1);
                }
            } else {
                rotatedWord = word.substring(word.length() - i - 1) + word.substring(0, word.length() - i - 1);
            }
            // Append the rotated word to `sb`
            sb.append(rotatedWord);

            // If `words[i]` had a punctuation mark at the end, add it back
            if (!noPunct) {
                sb.append(lastChar);
            }
            if (lastChar != '.') {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
oHell ldWor.
eWelcom to avaj mingprogram PO.
```

Comment: This code will IOUB if there are short words at the end of a long sentence. See the correct answer on this post for details and a solution.

Comment: when I take longer sentences, it throws StringIndexOutOfBoundException. what should be done?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash, now the second string goes out of bound exception if i add more  words to it

Comment: @AkshayShinde - I had fixed the issue after your comment but forgot to let you know. I hope, the updated answer fulfilled your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There are two minor issues that are causing your code to not function the way you intend. The first is that you are skipping over the last word in your line, because an `IntStream(0,4)` goes through `0,1,2,3` but not `4`, so you didn't need to do `IntStream.range(0, str.length-1)`
The second issue is that you are 0-indexing your words (Since that's the index of your array) but you *want* to 1-index your rotations. For this, simply do `mapToObj(i -> rotate(str[i], i+1)`

Overall, your big huge output line should read

```
outputFile.write(
                IntStream.range(0, str.length - 1)
                .mapToObj(i -> rotate(str[i], i))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
                + last + "\n");
```

There is also a case in your rotate function where  your rotate amount could be longer than the word's length, and in that case try to substring from a negative position. To fix this, make sure the rotate amount is within the range `[0, str.length() )` by doing:

```
position = ((position % str.length()) + str.length()) % str.length();
```

Comment: But when I do, outputFile.write(
                IntStream.range(0, str.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> rotate(str[i], i+1))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
                + last + "\n"); => this throws the following exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2

Comment: any thoughts on the above statements?

Comment: There is an issue with your rotate function. You did not consider the case where the word is shorter than the amount you want to rotate by. Consider the call `rotate("hi", 5);` What do you think will happen here?

Comment: It should be "ih" after 5th rotation

Comment: Yes. See the edit on this post to see how to fix your rotate function.

Comment: Yes. Like I detailed in my answer, add the line `position = ((position % str.length()) + str.length()) % str.length();` as the first line in the rotate method.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to identify the words. In rotating each word you need to be careful to handle cases where the right shift is greater than the length of the word:

```
static String reverse(String line)
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([\\s.,]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    for(int i=1; m.find(); i++) 
    {           
        String word = m.group(1);
        int idx = word.length() - (i % word.length());
        b.append(word.substring(idx));
        b.append(word.substring(0, idx));
        b.append(m.group(2));
    }
    return b.toString();        
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(reverse("Hello World."));
System.out.println(reverse("Welcome to java programming, it is really fun."));
```

Output:

```
oHell ldWor.
eWelcom to avaj mingprogram, ti is yreall unf.
```